# R package tourr: colour by a factor

Tags: r

I am looking at the excellent package tourr.
I am able to generate black dot animations eg:

```
 library(ggplot2)
 library(tourr)

 animate(flea[, 1:6])
```

But how can I generate animations with coloured dots by factor?
Example colour dots by magnitude, by year etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use ?`animate_stereo` it uses red-blue anaglyphs to display a 3d tour path.

```
animate_stereo(flea[, 1:6])
```

or something like :

```
animate(data = flea[, 1:6], tour_path = grand_tour(4),
        display = display_stereo(blue = rgb(0, 0, 1), 
                                 red  = rgb(1, 0, 0)))
```